# How to turn off Eula for OS X Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am trying to make a Minecraft server on OS X, but I have run into a snag. I downloaded the necessary files (I think) from https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula, but I don't know how to switch off Eula. Does anyone know how to switch it off?

Comment: The EULA is a legal document you agree to so that you can play Minecraft or use Mojang's services. It's not a program, and you can't "turn it off"

Comment: The reason it is there is that you must obey Mojang's terms of service to be legally allowed to run a Minecraft server. If you do not agree you may not use their code. So you can choose to not accept it, but the server program will not be allowed to run.

Answer (score 6):

You can't switch off the EULA. You have to read and accept them.

In your server's root directory, look for a file named *eula.txt* and append or set the last line to `eula=TRUE`. This indicates that you have read and accepted the EULA and the notification will go away.